# Is there a way to get the code of a pygame key using the string?

Tags: python, pygame

I am attempting to make something like a simple 2D game engine. It's not really, but kinda. The point of it is to allow for not just square tiling but triangular and hexagonal tiling as well. I'm using pygame for it, so it's also an easier way to access pygame. Anyways, I'm currently working on the button input. I have this rn:

```py
def keyboardInput(key: str):
    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.key.key_code(key)]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I think this is currently working tho but it seems like there’s still a problem. Maybe it’s with the code in main.py.

Comment: Why do you want your argument to be a string?

Comment: I want it to be a string because it’s meant to be its own module - pygame shouldn’t be required to use it.

Comment: No, there is no pygame function that converts a string into the pygame key enumerator. See [`pygame.key`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) module. You have to create your own dictionary that maps a string to a key.

Comment: Well then where can I get the values of all the keys?

Comment: Your question now does not match your title.  What is it you want to ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no pygame function that converts a string into the pygame key enumerator. See [`pygame.key`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) module. You have to create your own dictionary that maps a string to a key. e.g.:

```py
key_map = { 
    "left" : pygame.K_LEFT,
    "right" : pygame.K_RIGHT,
    ... 
}
```

```py
def keyboardInput(key: str):
     keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
     return key in key_map and keys[key_map[key]]
```

Alternatively you can get key enumerator constant with `getattr`:

```py
import pygame.locals

def keyboardInput(key: str):
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    try:
        return keys[getattr(pygame.locals, "K_" + key)]
    except:
        return keys[getattr(pygame.locals, "K_" + key.upper())]
```

---

In any case you need to handle the events. See [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) respectively [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

Therefor you must call `pygame.event.pump()` once in every frame. You can do this in an another function:

```py
def updateInput():
    pygame.event.pump()
```

Comment: I found the issue. It was with how I set up the testing code. I didn’t run the function to make the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getattr` to perform **any** kind of variable lookup:

```
key=getattr(pygame.locals,key)
```

Using `locals` reduces the number of meaningless hits (like `mixer`).  Of course, you could just write

```
from pygame import locals as magic
```

to provide the **real** constants as (say) `….magic.K_TAB`.  Or, if you want to provide a single module that has those constants **and** some interface of your own, do

```
from pygame.locals import *
```

in that module.  (It’s usually considered bad form to use `import *` to *avoid* qualification, but here you would be using it to *adapt* qualification.)

Comment: @Rabbid76: I don’t see any statement about the form of the string in the question.  One could upcase multi-character inputs and add `K_` if that mattered.  Of course, there **is** [key_code](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.key_code) in pygame 2, which was added to the question while I was writing a (more generic) answer and is probably a better answer to the original question!